# how to access request body from request without content-type header in play

Tags: java, playframework

I see this is a tough question for Play. A lot of people asked that question, but still it is not clear how to get bytes from request body if content type is not set in Java.

There is a solution in Scala, but it is not working for my case.
I want to use Play to built a http mock server in a test in Java.

@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Raw.class) has no sense

```
package org.dan;

import org.junit.Test;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.server.Server;

//import static play.mvc.Controller.request;
import static play.mvc.Results.ok;
import static play.routing.RoutingDsl.fromComponents;
import static play.server.Server.forRouter;

import static play.mvc.Http.Context.Implicit.request;

public class DemoPlayTest {
    @Test
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        Server server = forRouter(
                9001,
                (components) ->
                        fromComponents(components)                                
                                .POST("/echo")
                                .routeTo(DemoPlayTest::action)
                                .build());
        Thread.sleep(1111111);
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Raw.class)
    public static Result action() {
        return ok("Gut: " + request().body().asRaw() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
$ curl -v -X POST -d hello  http://localhost:9001/echo
Gut: null
```

Dependencies:

```
     <play.version>2.6.17</play.version>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-server_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${play.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-akka-http-server_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${play.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${play.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.dan;

import org.junit.Test;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.server.Server;

import static play.mvc.Controller.request;
import static play.mvc.Results.ok;
import static play.routing.RoutingDsl.fromComponents;
import static play.server.Server.forRouter;

public class DemoPlayTest {    
    @Test
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        Server server = forRouter(
                9001,
                (components) ->
                        fromComponents(components)                                    
                                .POST("/echo")
                                .routeTo(DemoPlayTest::action)
                                .build());
        Thread.sleep(1111111);
    }

    public static Result action() {
        final String body = new String(request().body().asBytes().toArray());
        return ok("Gut: " + body + "\n");
    }
}
```